# Populating a 3x3 table with images from php loop

Tags: php

I'm trying populate a table possibly a 3x3 with images from a php loop.
The way my code is set up I'm getting them all placed horizontal.
I wonder how could I get them to display side by side.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display Picture</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contentArea">
            <div id="content">
            <?php 
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
                mysql_select_db("tns");
                $res = mysql_query("select * from product");
                echo"<table align='center'>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    echo"<tr>"; 
                    echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="200" width="200" ><?php echo"<td>";
                    echo "<td>"; 
                    echo $row["Name"];echo"</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";      
                }                           
                echo"</table>";
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider putting all your DB data in an array, then using nested FOR loops - the outer one will print the rows, whereas the inner one will generate columns

Comment: So I've saved my db entries into an array.   But not sure as to how to set up the loop to create my table.                                           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
   $array[] = $row;         
 }

Answer (score 0):

you missed a `</td>` .

```
 echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="200" width="200" ><?php echo"</td>";
```

*you mentioned you want a 3X3 table . your table only seems to have two `<td>` tags . for a 3rd cell . include one more inside the `<tr>`*

---

for printing three images per row

*this is kinda a hacky solution, so if you got something better use that*

```
//we will print 3 image cells in each row and then a row break
echo"<tr>"; 

$i=0; //keeps count of the row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   $i=$i+1;

   echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="200" width="200" ><?php echo"</td>";

  if($i%3==0)
  {
    echo"</tr>"; 
  }


} 

//print a tr end in case the number of rows is not a multiple of 3
//no broken html
if($i%3!=0)
{   
   echo"</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, but that still doesn't fix my problem. I can only get the picture to display on top of each other and not side by side. The way my loop is set up doesn't cater for this. Looking for a solution to this. Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: @Sojav V Jose, Thanks for the reply, I got it sorted, have bigger problems now, haha... Thanks again.